# How can I check Previous View Controller in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift4

I want to reuse ViewController i.e **UserDataViewController**, For  Register and Profile updating. To do it I must know origin view controller. (Is it RegisterViewController or ProfileViewController?) How can I check? I need advice and a little bit example code, please.

Comment: From Where opened this view, RegisterViewController or ProfileViewController?

Comment: userdataViewController shows all textfields and other elements, and how can I know wrote it or update it?

Comment: @FaridValiyev : Please be clear and precise as to what you are expecting. Otherwise it might lead to closure of this question with reason - unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for my English. I will explain:
I have 3 view controller. 
First: RegisterViewController (Just show register benefits.)
Second: ProfileViewController (Just show profile information)
Third: userDataViewController (I want to create it reusable and use it for register and update.) That reason I want to know RegisterViewController open it or ProfileViewController. Is it clear?

Comment: Now I just use segue

Comment: Take a single UIViewController for managing profile and user registration. Bind it to a model class. While setting values in fields, check if model is nil or not nil. If nil then it should be Register use case else it should be profile use case. I can't think an easy way than this.

Comment: FROM REGISTER VIEW:  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerAddressToUserData", sender: self)

FROM PROFILE:  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ProfileToUserData", sender: self)

Comment: And I want catch which segue was used?

Comment: I used Show segue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a Show segue, then you are pushing onto a navigation stack. The userdataViewConroller, in its `viewDidAppear`, can find out what view controller is now one place further down the stack by saying this:

```
if let vcs = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    let previousVC = vcs[vcs.count - 2]
    if previousVC is RegisterViewController { 
        // ... and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Should we better use the metatype of the class with `RegisterViewController.self` ?

Answer (score 0):

> From Where opened this view, RegisterViewController or ProfileViewController?

based on this comment, if you are using navigation controller, you can do this by checking the navigation stack. If you are using presentation controller, you can check the presenting view controller.

But if you are OK having a reference of the object, then you can add a weak reference to the earlier controller. This can be done by dependency injection methods like prepare of segue or you can also do in the place where you create the object. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of finding previous view controller in **UserDataViewController** you should pass user data from **ProfileViewController** if want to use it for profile update. To do so you can add this function in **ProfileViewController**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let userDataVC = segue.destinationViewController as? UserDataViewController {
        userDataVC.user = self.user
    }
}
```

and in **UserDataViewController** add a variable for user.

```
var user: User?
```

and check in **viewDidLoad** method.

```
if let user = user {
      // Its Coming from ProfileViewController
      // Show User Information in textfields.
}
else {
     // Its Coming From RegisterViewController
}
```

**Benefits -** 
it will show user current information in textfields in case of profile update, which gives better user experience. - It saves user time to enter all information again. He updates only specific information that needs to be updated.